# Picasso/Glide loads only 6 thumbnails from youtube search result

Tags: java, android, picasso, android-glide

I am trying to load the thumbnails from youtube search result in a listview. But I get only the first 6 thumbnails and the rest of the imageViews are filled with black squares if I use Picasso and white squares if I use Glide.

Here is my custom array adapter:

```
        class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item>{
            public MyListAdapter(){
                super(SearchResult.this, R.layout.item_view, myItems);
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View itemView = convertView;
                if (itemView==null){
                    itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_view,parent,false);
                }

                Item currentItem = myItems.get(position);
                TextView title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
                title.setText(currentItem.getTitle());

                TextView uploader = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvUploader);
                uploader.setText(currentItem.getUploader());

                TextView timeNView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTimeNView);
                timeNView.setText(currentItem.getTimeNView());

                TextView duration = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDuration);
                duration.setText(currentItem.getDuration());

                ImageView thumb = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);


                Picasso.with(SearchResult.this).load(currentItem.getImageURL()).placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder).into(thumb);

                return itemView;
            }
        }
```

And the ImageView:

```
    <ImageView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

Comment: **1.** Why are you extending `ArrayAdapter` instead of `BaseAdapter`?
**2.** Why are you referring to `SearchResult.this` as context instead of passing a `Context` to the default constructor of the adapter?
**3.** Why are you not using a **static** Holder, instead of defining `thumb` every time?
**4.** Can you show what your `getLayoutInflater` does?
**5.** If using `ArrayAdapter` is not a must, may I suggest a different code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "black" views appeared because Picasso received empty urls (read the comments below to further understand why this happened).

Following is a code I suggested, including changes in structure and the fix for the problem (that was eventually found by *Eisenheim* himself) :

**1**. Instead of extending `ArrayAdapter`, I extended `BaseAdapter`
**2**. `Context` is now passed to the adapter's constructor
**3**. `LayoutInflater` is defined once, inside the constructor
**4**. static `Holder`s are holding the references (`R.id.imageView`, `R.id.tvDuration` ... ) to the views

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ArrayList<Item> myItems;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Item> myItems) {
        this.context = context;
        this.myItems = myItems;

        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return myItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return myItems.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0; //'0' is the default return value, you may change this if necessary
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        Holder holder;
        Item currentItem = (Item) getItem(position);

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_view, null);
            holder = new Holder();

            holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
            holder.uploader = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvUploader);
            holder.timeNView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTimeNView);
            holder.duration = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvDuration);
            holder.thumb = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.title.setText(currentItem.getTitle());
        holder.uploader.setText(currentItem.getUploader());
        holder.timeNView.setText(currentItem.getTimeNView());
        holder.duration.setText(currentItem.getDuration());

        Picasso.with(context).load("http://img.youtube.com/vi/" + 
                currentItem.getVideoId(‌​) + "/default.jpg").
                placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder).into(holder.thumb);

        return convertView;
    }

    static class Holder {
        TextView title, uploader, timeNView, duration;
        ImageView thumb;
    }
}
```

Comment: The result is still the same. I think I figured out what actually went wrong. I ran a random search on youtube, disconnected the modem and started to scroll down. Then I noticed there were only 6 thumbnails loaded and the rest were blank because I deliberately turned off network connection to see what's happening!

So I generated the thumbnails using `http://img.youtube.com/vi/id/default.jpg` this URL replacing the `id` with currentItem.getVideoId(). Now it working just fine.

Now in your implementation of BaseAdapter, it seems the ListView isn't using the custom `item_view` layout.

Comment: TextViews have become gray and misaligned with ImageView. It's worth mentioning that I couldn't use public (for MyAdapter) and static (for Holder) modifiers since they were inside an AsyncTask class.

Comment: I'm glad you found the problem! I ran the above code in a new project and it of course works. Using a static Holder is the correct way to go, you'll notice the difference when your data set (myItems) gets bigger, or when you run the same code on different devices. You don't want to define references each time. This is exactly why you check for `convertView == null`. I'd check the parent parameter (null) that I set to the inflater and the context that you pass. Try solving the problems using this code (the structure is taken from a Google's explanation of how to correctly customize `getView` )

Comment: And as for your original problem: it happened because `Picasso` creates and uses its own cache. When you disonnected, it cached the "black" images and then loaded those same cached images each time. Uninstalling your app/clearing its cache (and then successfully downloading the images) would have also solved the problem.

Comment: When I said I ran a search on youtube, I was referring to the youtube website, not the app. I think you misunderstood that and that's ok since I didn't provide enough info. Neither Picasso, nor its cache has anything to do with this problem. Youtube itself is responsible for those black images. How? As I mentioned earlier when I hit the search button on youtube the returned result contains the thumbs only for the first 6 videos (I am on a 1366x768 monitor, a bigger resolution might have a few more). As I keep scrolling down, the rest of the thumbs gradually start loading.

Comment: This phenomenon goes unnoticed with the internet connection enabled. So I decided to run a little experiment. I searched something on youtube website and then disabled the connection to see what happens when I scroll down. And when I scrolled down, I found that the rest of the thumbs couldn't be generated, which means the `src` attribute that I was targeting as the source of Picasso.load(/path/to/image) was not generated too. How can Picasso load an image with no image source provided? So it starts putting those black squares instead.

Comment: Right, so instead of throwing a malformed url exception,  Picasso loaded a default black image

Comment: So how did I overcome that? `http://img.youtube.com/vi/id/default.jpg` - This URL can generate thumbs for the videos. But the `id` has to be replaced with the youtube ID. So I used it as the source for Picasso. Could you please update the answer replacing the Picasso call with: `Picasso.with(context).load("http://img.youtube.com/vi/"+currentItem.getVideoId()+"/default.jpg").placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder).into(holder.thumb);` so that I can accept it as answer? Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use a RecyclerView because it reduces the load on the system, therefore you have more processing and memory to cache more images. Make sure that your images are not too big or use the option in Picasso or Glide to crop them to the size you need, plus as the previous answer said, debug to see that you are not setting empty URLs.

Kind regards!